# IDE to recognize Cucumber steps in TypeScript format

Tags: typescript, protractor, webstorm, cucumberjs

Have tried to use WebStorm as IDE for developing cucumber-protractor tests. The problem is that when trying to create the steps I only get the option to create them in Cucumber JS. If put into a TypeScript file, the steps are executed via npm run e2e but in the WebStorm IDE these appear as not implemented.

Can this be done in WebStorm? Is there another tool to use? (eg: VS Code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently supported:( Please vote for [WEB-29665](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29665), [WEB-22516](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22516) and linked tickets

Answer (score 0):

VSCode indeed supports it via the [Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete) plugin.